# Android bulk file output from ZIP file

Tags: android, performance, zip, fileoutputstream

I download a pretty large zip file from online, and then want to extract it to my application's storage. This takes a decent amount of time right now, and I was wondering if there were any suggestions on how to speed it up. I know for a SQLite Database you can do a bulk insert by calling beginTransaction() and was wondering if there was anything similar for actual file output. Here's what I've got so far:

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(zis);
BufferedOutputStream bos;
byte buffer[] = new byte[8 * 1024];
int n;
try {
ZipEntry ze = null;

while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
{
    String name = ze.getName();
    if (!ze.isDirectory() && !name.contains("MACOSX"))
    {
        name = prefix + ze.getName();
        name = name.replace('/', '_');
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(mContext.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));


        while ((n = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
            bos.write(buffer, 0, n);

        Log.i("Update", name + " is saved to internal storage.");
        zis.closeEntry();
        bos.close();
    }
}
} finally {
in.close();
zis.close();
}
```

Comment: Extracting a Zip file means that you are decompressing the data from the zip and writing individual files on the disk, which depends majorly on I/O speed and processing as well. I may stand corrected, but I am not sure if you could do anything to speed this process up without increasing the actual I/O speeds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extrakting Zip to SD-Card is very slow. How can i optimize performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975847/extrakting-zip-to-sd-card-is-very-slow-how-can-i-optimize-performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read and write data byte by byte. Try to read and write more data at time, using some buffer instead. Byte by byte for a really large file may be too much even for the phone SSD, a lot of small size writes are the most challenging for these devices.

```
  byte buffer [] = new byte[2048];
  int n;
  while ( (n = in.read(buffer) > 0) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, n);
  }
```

Comment: I had just set up a Buffered Output Stream when I saw this comment! Thanks. I've updated my code to reflect what I currently have. Is it alright if I use 8kb buffer instead of a 2kb buffer?

Comment: Probably any size you want, just above some clever limit increasing the size does not longer adds much performance.