# Android: opening large zip file

Tags: android, zip

I cannot unzip a large file (50 mb).
I have tried both `ZipInputStream` and `ZipFile`.

I am getting the following exception when I use `ZipFile`:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: EOCD not found; not a Zip archive?

When I use `ZipInputStream` I get the follower error:

> there is no zip entry(zin.getNextEntry())

`ZipInputStream` Code:

```
public static void unzip(File _zipFile, File directory) throws IOException {
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            // not getting here
        }
        zin.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

`ZipFile` Code :

```
public static void unzipa(File zipfile, File directory) throws IOException {
    try {
        ZipFile zfile = new ZipFile(zipfile); // getting exception here
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zfile.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

        }
        zfile.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ErroHandling.HandleError(ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extrakting Zip to SD-Card is very slow. How can i optimize performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975847/extrakting-zip-to-sd-card-is-very-slow-how-can-i-optimize-performance)

Answer (score 1):

If a `ZipException` or `IOException` is being thrown when initializing `ZipFile` then you should test the integrity of the ZIP. You may also want to make sure you have read/write access. If you are unzipping this file on Android's internal storage (sdcard) you need to have the following permission declared in your AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The code looks okay to me, but here is a solution I cooked up real quick and tested on a valid ZIP file larger than 100 MB:

```
public static boolean unzip(final File zipFile, final File destinationDir) {
    ZipFile zip = null;
    try {
        zip = new ZipFile(zipFile);
        final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipFileEntries = zip.entries();
        while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
            final ZipEntry entry = zipFileEntries.nextElement();
            final String entryName = entry.getName();
            final File destFile = new File(destinationDir, entryName);
            final File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();
            if (destinationParent != null && !destinationParent.exists()) {
                destinationParent.mkdirs();
            }
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                final BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                        zip.getInputStream(entry));
                int currentByte;
                final byte data[] = new byte[2048];
                final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                final BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 2048);
                while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, 2048)) != -1) {
                    dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
                }
                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (zip != null) {
            try {
                zip.close();
            } catch (final IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am getting exception in the line zip = new ZipFile(zipFile);
java.util.zip.ZipException: EOCD not found; not a Zip archive?
I can able to open the zip file in the desktop. i can able to open if i reduce the file size to 10 mb(removed some file from the zip).